# Export objects and classes before their declaration makes them undefined

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I try to repeat example from [Mozilla Hacks](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/) (**Export lists** subtitle):

```
//export.js
export {detectCats, Kittydar};
function detectCats() {}
class Kittydar {}

//import.js
import {detectCats, Kittydar} from "./export.js";
console.log(detectCats); // function detectCats() {}
console.log(Kittydar); // undefined
```

Oops: Kittydar is undefined (btw., the problem is the same with simple `Object`).

But if I put `export` after `Kittydar` declaration it's ok:

```
//export.js
class Kittydar {}
export {Kittydar};

//import.js
import {Kittydar} from "./export.js";
console.log(Kittydar); // function Kittydar() {_classCallCheck(this, Kittydar);}
```

Is this a typo in the article?

I transpile this with `babel` and bundle with `browserify`. Then I include output bundle in a usual `.html` file (with `<script>` tag).

Comment: Since there is no JavaScript environment that supports ES6 modules, I assume you are using a transpiler to convert ES6 module to another module system. That transpiler doesn't seem to be handling classes correctly in this case. AFAIK what you have should work according to the ES6 spec.

Comment: Hmm... I use `grunt-babel@5.0.1` which uses `babel-core@5.8.23`. Ok, I'm going to check it with pure and last `babel` version.

Comment: @FelixKling, I've repeated it with latest `babel@6.3.26` and `browserify@12.0.1`. The same behaviour. Can it be a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard is hard to follow on this, but **the article is correct**. This code works in [es6draft](https://github.com/anba/es6draft) and in the SpiderMonkey shell: both the function and the class are initialized by the time those `console.log` calls run.

Here's how it's supposed to work, in minute detail:

- The JS engine parses import.js. It sees the `import` declaration, so then it loads export.js and parses it as well.
- Before actually running any of the code, the system creates both module scopes and populates them with all the top-level bindings that are declared in each module. (The spec calls this [ModuleDeclarationInstantiation](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-moduledeclarationinstantiation).) A `Kittydar` binding is created in export.js, but it's uninitialized for now.

  In import.js, a `Kittydar` *import binding* is created. It's an alias for the `Kittydar` binding in export.js.
- export.js runs. The class is created. `Kittydar` is initialized.
- import.js runs. Both `console.log()` calls work fine.

---

**Babel's implementation of ES6 modules is nonstandard.**

I think it's deliberate. Babel aims to compile ES6 modules into ES5 code that works with an existing module system of your choice: you can have it spit out AMD modules, UMD, CommonJS, etc. So if you ask for AMD output, your code might be ES6 modules, but the ES5 output is an AMD module and it's going to behave like an AMD module.

Babel could probably be more standard-compliant while still integrating nicely with the various module systems, but there are tradeoffs.