# Seemingly fine typescript code comes back with runtime errors

Tags: typescript

All of this compiles fine using tsc. I am confused about why I am getting the runtime error "myTest is not a function" - In fact, anything coming from this module is 'undefined' - I've attempted to export a class with static methods, even assigning myTest as a simple variable with a string value. All all of those come back undefined. Furthermore, I have other modules being exported from elsewhere in the project and all of those values seem work to fine.

./commands-setup/index.ts

```js
export {
    myTest,
};

let myTest: Function = (): string => {
    return 'testString';
};
```

./main.ts

```js
import { myTest, } from './commands-setup';
console.log('Test result: ' + myTest());
```

Comment: Why not `export myTest = ...`? Then you don't fall into the temporal dead zone.

Comment: > "even assigning myTest as a simple variable with a string value"

I did, this is just where I ended. 
Apparently changing the directory name from 'commands-setup' allows it to function. For some reason tsc is changing it to 
```commands_setup_1.myTest```. Not sure if that has anything to do with this. I'm not why but it seems this namespace is broken or something in node /shrug

Comment: So changing away from "commands-setup" as the directory name allowed this to function. I validated this by changing it back to "commands-setup" and was able to reproduce the error. I did this back and fourth 3 times in disbelief. I committed my changes on git and now none of it is failing regardless of the directory name. I'm completely lost as to why this was happening.

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting `myTest` before you are setting it. So the exported property will be undefined. You need to move the export statement under the declaration:

```
let myTest: Function = (): string => {
    return 'testString';
};

export {
  myTest
};
```

You could also, instead, just export the function immediately like so:

```
export const myTest = (): string => {
  return `testString`;
}
```

Comment: That's probably not it because it's working now. And the code looks the same. I've been putting the export statement at the beginning for this entire project and have had no problems

Comment: It should be noted I'm using 'export' not 'module.exports' - 'module.exports' would behave as you are describing.

Comment: ```export const myTest = (): string => {
  return `testString`;
}``` I tried this - it did not work. But I can't test anymore as it seems its working again :/

Comment: [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604772/export-objects-and-classes-before-their-declaration-makes-them-undefined)